# How to add special price for customer group in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, products, customer-group, special-price

In magento products, admin have option to add customer group price. I also want to add customer group special price. There is already special price option in the products but it is for all customer groups.

Here is group prices screenshot:
[image]

So in the group price option I want to add one more input field named 'special price'. so this price can be used as special price for specific customer group.

Does someone have a suggestion?

Comment: You want a special price for a group? Then just add another group and make the price for that group. I´m confused by your question, can you give an example please

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using:

```
Promotions > Catalog Price Rule > Add New Rule in Magento admin panel
```

there you can select customer group, date from when to when the discount applies and can make **BIG** conditions filter which the customer will have to satisfy to get that *customer group special price*.

At this "conditions" stage you choose **"name filter" and specify "the product name" to which this promotion rule will apply**, as well can add some other matching that product only criteria to make sure this rule stays only on that product. And thats it.

P.S. *I love this option: it, in some way, creates a lot of options which are not present in product page.*